# Using sql data base in c# class Library

Tags: c#, sql

[image]

[image]

I have a problem, that I can't reference SQL Server database project in a class library project to manage database (insert, delete and more...).

I want to build "book store system" solution with uwp project, class library project that holds base classes and derives classes, and another class library that holds manager class with functions that manage the system.

I tried to create new SQL Server database project and succeeded to access a database that I created in SSMS. But when I tried to reference it from the class library by using Publish command it didn't work.

I didn't use actually code but I tried to use the buttons

I expected that it will open me the option to call reference

Comment: You need to look at the connection string if the publish didn't work.  Your connection string could be connecting to a path that doesn't exist or the credentials are wrong.  You should never use a connection string that uses the mdf file name (attached).  The database is already attached to the server and does not need to get attached again.  Attaching often creates credential issues because the database is owned by the server (usually an admin account) and locks normal uses from access to the mdf file.  The sql server has the pathname of the file when the database is attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think you can use [EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) with code first application or database first style if you like to manage database by your self and easily deal with context classes that mapping database tables you can find full example [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx)